# Solr: sorry, no dataimport-handler defined

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to index my data from oracle database in Solr. For this, I made a core named 'orca' in Solr. My database table name is school which has three fields namely id,name and pricipal. Following are my files:

**schema.xml** file:

```
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <!-- Fields added for oracle school table load-->
 <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="principal" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**data-config.xml** file:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE" user="system" password="*****"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="school" query="select * from school">
            <field column="id" name="id" />
            <field column="name" name="name" />
            <field column="principal" name="principal" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**solrconfig.xml** file:

```
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" /> 
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" /> 
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" /> 
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" /> 
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" /> 
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" /> 
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" /> 
   <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" /> 

  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

All these three files are located at **solr-5.3.0\server\solr\orca\conf**.

It is not giving any error but also not defining dataimport-handler.

I am not able to figure out what is the mistake. Please help!

Comment: I got same problem. Have you a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Do a check of  just have 3 things :

1. Loading the required jar lib statement in solrconfig.xml
2. Adding the handler definition which points to your data-config file
3. Add the data-config file.

If you are still facing the same issue get a good example on the same or copy all the files and then modify the changes as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Abhijit. But as you can see from the code, I am already doing all these. Still it's not working. Can you provide some good example for the same? Thanks in advance!

Comment: here are some https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler  http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/how-to-use-solr-data-import-handler-to.html  http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-solr/solr-dataimporthandler-example/

Comment: I have exact same issue. Did you find any solutions to this problem? Thanks

Comment: What is the issue for you? do you see any error in the logs?